# how can i set orderbychild inside FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a phone directory app and I want to show different Categories data in different activities. I want to help people to find their information very easily in different category wise 
It shows me all the data in the database. but I don't want that I want to show there only "ambulance contact" category data.

```
package com.example.moulvibazarinfo.allCatagory;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.moulvibazarinfo.AllAdapters.DataSetFire;
import com.example.moulvibazarinfo.AllAdapters.DetailsViewActivity;
import com.example.moulvibazarinfo.AllAdapters.FirebaseViewHolder;
import com.example.moulvibazarinfo.AllAdapters.SubmitedContact;
import com.example.moulvibazarinfo.R;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AmbulanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<DataSetFire> arrayList;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataSetFire> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSetFire, FirebaseViewHolder> adapter;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ambulance);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.ambulanceRecycleListViewID);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        arrayList = new ArrayList<DataSetFire>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MiContact");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);




        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSetFire>().setQuery(databaseReference, DataSetFire.class).build();


        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSetFire, FirebaseViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FirebaseViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final DataSetFire model) {

            //filtering database




                holder.nameTextView.setText("name: "+model.getName());
                holder.institutionNameTextView.setText("institution Name: "+model.getInstitutionName());
                holder.emailTextView.setText("Email: "+model.getEmail());
                holder.numberTextView.setText("Number: "+model.getNumber());
                holder.categoryTextView.setText("category: "+model.getCategory());
                holder.addressTextView.setText("address: "+model.getAddress());


                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AmbulanceActivity.this,DetailsViewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",model.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("institutionName",model.getInstitutionName());
                        intent.putExtra("email",model.getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("number",model.getNumber());
                        intent.putExtra("category",model.getCategory());
                        intent.putExtra("address",model.getCategory());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FirebaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new FirebaseViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(AmbulanceActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
            }
        };


        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Please, somebody, help me! I am new in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order data in the Firebase Realtime Database, you can use its `orderByChild()` method:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MiContact");
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("category");

options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSetFire>().setQuery(query, DataSetFire.class).build();
```

*This assumes the property is called `category` in our JSON. If it has a different name, update the `orderByChild(...)` call.*

The rest of your code can remain the same. With this simple change the database server, Firebase SDK, and FirebaseUI adapter, work together to show the contacts in the requested order.

---

**Edit**: if you want to filter to only show items with `category` equal to `Ambulance`, you can do so by changing the query like this:

```
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Ambulance");
```

---

I highly recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), and maybe also the [codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: i was write this before but its work exactly like your code .but problem is its showing other catagory data in the botton i dont want that  `options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSetFire>().setQuery(databaseReference.orderByChild("category").startAt("Ambulance"), DataSetFire.class).build();`

Comment: I added an example to the answer of how to filter only child nodes with a specific value for `category`.